# The order between AddMvc/AddSwaggerGen and UseMvc/UseSwagger(UI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-2.2, swagger-3.0

When I power my APIs with Swagger, I follow one of [those guids](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-swagger-to-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api/) and I always put the MVC injections before Swagger injections like this.

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddSwaggerGen(_ => { ... });

app.UseMvc();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { ... });
```

A friend of mine asked why I apply that order and not handle the Swagger related lines first, before MVC. I discovered that I couldn't explain that to him nor motivate it (other than a very embarrassed *well... that's the way it is...*). That tells me that I should dig a bit into that matter.

Short googling revealed nothing of relevance as far I've noticed, so I'm asking here.

Comment: The docs should be of some help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, `Add*` is  not affected by the order they are added to the service collection.

However, depending on the implementation of the particular `Add*` extension, the order may affect configuration. For example, if internally it uses the `TryAdd*` extension, then only the first call registers. Subsequent calls wont add as a registration would already exist.

The general `AddScoped/AddSingleton/AddTransient` calls recognizes the last call for a type as it overrides the previous registration calls for that type. When registering multiple implementations for a type, for resolving via `IEnumerable<T>` then the implementations in the collection will be in the order they were registered.

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

For the `Use*` middleware the order they are added to the pipeline is important as they are invoked in the same order.

> ### **Order**
>
> The order that middleware components are added in the `Startup.Configure` method defines the order in which the middleware
>   components are invoked on requests and the reverse order for the
>   response. The order is critical for security, performance, and
>   functionality.

Reference [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

In my experience, depending on their designed purpose, some 3rd party integrations (including swagger) that need access to the pipeline suggest adding their extensions after `AddMvc` to try and avoid route conflicts.

Most security (Authentication/Authorization) and logging middleware are usually suggested to be added early in the pipeline, so they tend to come before `AddMvc`.

Comment: _Short story is Add* is not affected by the order they are added to the service collection_ maybe be true for the above case, but not in general and depends on the implementation of the `Add*` method. If you have two `Add*` extension methods with `TryAdd*`calls within `Add*` method, then order do matter, since only the first one will add its registration, the second wouldn't add if an registraiton exists.

Comment: @Tseng Good point. I'll see how I can reword my initial sentence to incorporate that.

Comment: Also the later `AddScoped/AddSingleton/AddTransient` calls overrides the resolving of an previously registered object (when a single instance is resolved, `IEnumerable<T>` will return all registrations in the order they were registered)  iirc and a [ReplaceAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.removeall?view=aspnetcore-2.1) could be called within a `.AddXxx` extension method xD